# How do I get Bjarne Stoustroup's simple graphics program to work in VS2019?

Tags: c++, api, graphics, fltk

I'm currently reading Bjarne Stroustrup's 'Principles and Practice using C++ 2nd edition' and I just started chapter 12. But I can't seem to get this code running.

```
#include "Simple_window.h" // get access to our window library
#include "Graph.h" // get access to our graphics library facilities
int main()
{
 using namespace Graph_lib; // our graphics facilities are in Graph_lib
 Point tl {100,100}; // to become top left corner of window
 Simple_window win {tl,600,400,"Canvas"}; // make a simple window
 Polygon poly; // make a shape (a polygon)
 poly.add(Point{300,200}); // add a point
 poly.add(Point{350,100}); // add another point
 poly.add(Point{400,200}); // add a third point
 poly.set_color(Color::red); // adjust properties of poly
 win.attach (poly); // connect poly to the window
 win.wait_for_button(); // give control to the display engine
}
```

The error messages:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0135   class "Simple_window" has no member "attach"    Project7    c:\Users\HP\source\repos\Project7\Project7\Source.cpp   13  
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "GUI.h" Project7    c:\Users\HP\source\repos\Project7\Project7\Simple_window.h  2   
Error (active)  E0725   name must be a namespace name   Project7    c:\Users\HP\source\repos\Project7\Project7\Simple_window.h  4   
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "Graph.h"   Project7    c:\Users\HP\source\repos\Project7\Project7\Source.cpp   2   
Error (active)  E0725   name must be a namespace name   Project7    c:\Users\HP\source\repos\Project7\Project7\Source.cpp   5   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "Point" is undefined Project7    c:\Users\HP\source\repos\Project7\Project7\Source.cpp   6   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "Polygon" is undefined   Project7    c:\Users\HP\source\repos\Project7\Project7\Source.cpp   8   
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "Point" is undefined Project7    c:\Users\HP\source\repos\Project7\Project7\Source.cpp   9   
Error (active)  E0018   expected a ')'  Project7    c:\Users\HP\source\repos\Project7\Project7\Source.cpp   9   
Error (active)  E0018   expected a ')'  Project7    c:\Users\HP\source\repos\Project7\Project7\Source.cpp   10  
Error (active)  E0018   expected a ')'  Project7    c:\Users\HP\source\repos\Project7\Project7\Source.cpp   11  
Error (active)  E0276   name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name Project7    c:\Users\HP\source\repos\Project7\Project7\Source.cpp   12  
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'GUI.h': No such file or directory    Project7    c:\users\hp\source\repos\project7\project7\simple_window.h  2
```

I tried pasting the header files specified in the code into my program but it doesn't work. I've tried implementing FLTK 1.3.5 and linking it to VS2019 too but it continues to display error messages. Please help me with this problem.

Here's a reference to that chapter in his book: https://www.stroustrup.com/programming_ch12.pdf

Comment: What are the error messages? Copy and paste them into the question.

Comment: Hello. I have updated it.

Comment: But the thing about these header files is that they refer to other non-standard header files and so on. Nowhere in the book does Stoustrup elaborate on how to run this program step by step and where to find the libraries he's used.

Comment: *"cannot open source file "GUI.h" Project7    c:\Users\HP\source\repos\Project7\Project7\Simple_window.h  2   "* where's GUI.h?

Comment: GUI.h is the header for Simple_window.h

Comment: Your compiler can't find it.

Comment: DId you read Appendix D: "Installing FLTK"?

Comment: I have and it was said to be wildly out of date.